# Expect that some method was called on mock object. Does it break encapsulation?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

Consider the following code:

```
class SomeInterface
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~SomeInterface() {}
};

class RealImplementation : public SomeInterface
{
public:
    void foo() { /* do complete stuff */}
};

class MockImplementation : public SomeInterface
{
public:
    void foo() { /* do simple stuff */ }
};
```

To be more concrete there is some example:

```
class IInjector
{
public:
    virtual bool injectDLL() const = 0;
    virtual ~IInjector() {}
};

class RealInjector : public IInjector
{
public:
    bool injectDLL() const
    {
        int pid = GetHookedProcessId();
        char name = readDllNameFromSomewhere();
        if (loadDllInSomeProcess(pid, name))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

class Hook
{
public:
    bool hookProcess(const IInjector& injector)
    {
        return injector.injectDLL();
    }
};
```

Then in test code it is the common case to do something like this:

```
class MockInjector : public IInjector {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(injectDLL, bool());
};

TEST(HookTest, CanHookSomething) {
    MockInjector injector;                          
    EXPECT_CALL(injector, injectDLL()).Times(1);

    Hook hook;
    EXPECT_TRUE(hook.hookProcess(injector));
}
```

For verifying that `injectDLL` method was called we must know that `hookProcess` called `injectDLL`. But it is the implementation details of method `hookProcess`. So, in our test we open some implementation details. But it is very common case. So, does it ok to open some implementation details when using mocks?

Comment: What do you to test for `Hook` ?

Comment: @Jarod42, I test that hook process return true with my mock injector and that method injectDLL called on mock injector object

Comment: So you are mostly right, you forget to specify return value of the mock (and so, you probably need 2 test cases).

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you for your answer but the question is not about technical details of using gmock. The question is about whether is it ok that for mocking we must open some implementation details?

Comment: I meant, is calling `injectDLL()` twice an error? It is you who know what you want to test for `Hook`. If you change implementation, ideally, you should not change the test. (Currently `Hook` has only one method without logic).

Answer (score 1):

Unit-testing is normally applied as a white box testing technique - you know the code under test.  Otherwise, you would also not be able to make statements about code coverage achieved by your tests.  And, unit-test code is considered as belonging to the code, put under version control together with the code etc..  Thus, for your unit-test you don't 'disclose' implementation details - they are not hidden anyway.

However, certainly with mocking your tests become more dependent on the implementation details, which means, they are more likely to break or need maintenance.  But that is just a tradeoff you may have to accept in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the function specification of `Hook::injectProcess` is to use a user-supplied `IInjector` instance to inject the DLL, any implementation of `injectProcess` that does not invoke the `injectDLL` method on that user-supplied instance is surely broken. So in the example case you provide, there seems to be no break of encapsulation at all.

The example you show is a good example of dependency injection done ideal for testing with frameworks like Google Test. It allows some specific operations that are formalized in public interfaces to be mocked away by calling public functions with user-constructible mock objects.

In the general case, though, code like this might break encapsulation. Consider the function under test not to be a `hookProcess` method, whose *clearly specified job* is to inject a DLL, so you know for sure that a DLL has to be injected. You might want to test a function that should obtain some data, and currently it needs to inject some DLLs into some processes to do that, but there might be other ways in obtaining that information that involves no DLL injection or injecting different DLLs into different processes. In that case, testing for which DLLs get injected where *does* break the encapsulation provided by the "just get the information anyhow" specification. This case is discussed by the answer by Dirk Herrmann.